# Database Table Relationships having foreign keys in both child and parent table

Tags: database-design

Let's say we have two tables CUSTOMER and VEHICLE having one to many relationships. VEHICLE has a CUSTOMERID as a foreign key in it which makes it a child table. The question is, Why i cannot have VEHICLEID as a foreign key into CUSTOMER table. I know it is not correct way, but i need to know the more detailed and in depth reason why it is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and it's a common way of modeling one-to-many relationship where one of the children is "special".

The resulting cyclical dependency (and chicken-and-egg problem when inserting new data) is resolved by making one of the FKs NULL-able, or by deferring its enforcement to the end of the transaction (if your DBMS supports deferred constraints).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just wanted a second opinion and glad to know that the solution i was thinking is not considred "WRONG" , it is just a "SPECIAL" case which is better to be avoided for a cleaner design.

Answer (score 0):

Because you will be able to add only one vehicle for each customer... like one vehicle id by row... one row = one customer in a table!

And your first foreign key do all the job a foreign key does. No need another foreign key reverse! 2 cross foreign key will make a creation of an insert in both table impossible...

Comment: hmmm your argument about inserts becoming impossible makes alot sense, but what if i add a foreign key to the customer table as well and make it nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You can, you just need to understand the type of relationship between the tables.  Is it 1-1?  1-many?  many-many?  Can one customer have only one vehicle, or can they have more than one?  If one customer can have more than one vehicle, then it's a 1-many relationship as you describe.

On the other hand, with a vehicle FK in the customer table, then you're saying each vehicle can have multiple customers, which may not match your requirement.

Or it could be a many-many relationship, where one customer can have multiple vehicles, and each vehicle can be related to multiple customers.  In that case, you need a customerVehicle table with the pair of FKs (one customerID, one vehicleID.)

---

in response to your comment, you really need to explain your requirement, or what you're trying to do.  You can implement your keys however you want, after it's deployed it will fail if you're not doing what you're required to do.

a one-to-one relationship can always be represented by one table, so if that's your requirement, that one customer can have only one vehicle that no other customer can have, you don't need a related vehicle table at all.  All the fields from the vehicle table can be moved to the customer table.

Comment: ok. so what if i add a foreign key to the Customer table and implement a unique constraint on it? That raises another question, How do we enforce one-to-one relationship and if we can enforce one record par table then why can't we add foreign key (VEHICLEID) to the parent table (CUSTOMER) and enforce uniqness.